# newtonsoft.json deserializing logic

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to parse a json string with for example [1,2,3] to an array during deserializing.

This is my json data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "district": "1",
        "lon": "4.420650000000000000",
        "lat": "51.21782000000000000",
        "bikes": "19",
        "slots": "14",
        "zip": "2018",
        "address": "Koningin Astridplein",
        "addressNumber": null,
        "nearbyStations": "3,4,5,24",
        "status": "OPN",
        "name": "001- Centraal Station - Astrid"
    }
]
```

And this is my c# currently mapping to a regular string, which i would like to be an array of integers.

```
var AvailabilityMap = new[] { new Station() };
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, AvailabilityMap);

public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public int Bikes { get; set; }
    public int Slots { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string NearbyStations { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have found no way so far to do this in a proper way, without looping trough my current array once more..

Comment: Are you trying to get nearbyStations as array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom converter. Something like this:

```
public class StringToIntEnumerable : JsonConverter
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return false;    // we'll stick to read-only. If you want to be able 
                             // to write it isn't that much harder to do.
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Note: I've skipped over a lot of error checking and trapping here
        // but you might want to add some
        var str = reader.Value.ToString();
        return str.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now change you class to use the converter by using the `JsonConverterAttribute`:

```
public class Station
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public int Bikes { get; set; }
    public int Slots { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToIntEnumerable))]
    public IEnumerable<int> NearbyStations { get; set; }  // or List<int> or int[] if 
                                                          // you prefer, just make 
                                                          // sure the convert returns 
                                                          // the same type
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And now to deserialize:

```
var stations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Station>>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNr4br) that uses a custom `JsonConverter`.

What we're doing is converting your CSV values into a proper JSON array *before* we convert the entire JSON string into a `Station` object.

## Custom `JsonConverter`

`ReadJson` reads through the JSON string. First, it loads the JSON into a `JObject`. Next, it gets the `nearbyStations` property and changes it from a simple CSV string into a JavaScript array. It does this by wrapping the CSV within square brackets. Finally, we use the `JsonSerializer` to populate our target object and return it.

`CanWrite` is set to `false`, because this `JsonConverter` is only allowed to read JSON not write to JSON. As a result, we don't need to implement `WriteJson`. The `CanConvert` tests to make sure that the target object is a `Station`.

```
public class StationConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader r, Type t, object v, JsonSerializer s)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(r);

        var prop = jObject.Property("nearbyStations");
        var wrapped = string.Format("[{0}]", prop.Value);
        JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(wrapped);
        prop.Value = jsonArray;

        var target = new Station();
        s.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter w, object v, JsonSerializer s)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary: CanWrite is false.");
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (Station);
    }
}
```

## Change the `Station` Class to have an `int[]`

For the above `JsonConverter` to to work, change your `NearbyStations` property to be an `int[]`.

```
public int[] NearbyStations
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

## Usage Example [with Live Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNr4br)

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
var AvailabilityMap = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Station[]>(json, new StationConverter());

Console.WriteLine(AvailabilityMap[0].NearbyStations[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is to have properly formatted input. In this case:

```
 "nearbyStations": ["3","4","5","24"]
```

But I was faced with a similar situation in which the data could not be updated, so a solution had to be found. The easiest is to make a getter/setter that won't be touched by the serializer/deserializer. Unfortunately you can't ignore public properties with this serializer out of the box. So you have to do some clever work-arounds like reading into a DTO and using a business object for actual operations.

```
public class StationDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public int Bikes { get; set; }
    public int Slots { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string NearbyStations { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
public class Station : StationDTO
{
    public List<string> NearbyStationsList
    { 
        get 
        {
            return NearbyStations.Split(',');
        }

        set
        {
            NearbyStations = string.Join(",", value);
        }
    }
}
```

More information: [Newtonsoft ignore attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309725/newtonsoft-ignore-attributes)

Comment: I'm not in control of the external data, so thanks for this tip.