# Serialize Model after removing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First off, I'm a garbage C# developer, so don't flame me, but below is what I'm trying to do and a code example of what I'm trying but isn't working.

Goal: Take a model, serialize it into json, write that json to a file on disk.

Model:

```
namespace My.Dope.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Theme
    {
        [DisplayName("Company Name: ")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Slogan: ")]
        public string Slogan { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Primary Color: ")]
        public string PrimaryColor { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Large Logo: ")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase LargeLogo { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Small Logo: ")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase SmallLogo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Some code to maybe serialize it and save it to disk:

```
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"D:\test_theme_json.txt"))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    //serialize object directly into file stream
                    serializer.Serialize(file, theme);
                }
```

Error:

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

I think it's because of the `HttpPostedFileBase` items in the model, but I actually don't need those serialized into the JSON file. How can I remove those items, and turn the rest of the model into a .json file that gets saved to the disk?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> I actually don't need those serialized into the JSON file

In JSON.NET there is a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute that you can decorate properties with.

Related: [Newtonsoft ignore attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309725/newtonsoft-ignore-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

To serialize and write it to a file, just do this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theme);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("yourfile.json", json);
```