# How to remove a child from System.Object object?

Tags: c#

At a Rest-API I got an incoming object from Type System.Object.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileRegistration([FromBody]object incomingObject)
```

This object I would like to parse into my type.

```
public class MyType
{
  public string name;
  public double age;
}
```

The incoming object can has one more attribute "version" and the content of version can look different each time.

```
{"name":"Gisela", "age":29.64}
{"name":"Gisela", "age":29.64, "version":"new"}
{"name":"Gisela", "age":29.64, "version":2.0}
{"name":"Gisela", "age":29.64, "version":["param1":17,"param2":"oho"]}
{"name":"Gisela", "age":29.64, "version":true}
```

In case this object has a child with name "version". I want to remove this child and put it into a string. In the parent object the child should be removed.

How to do this?

I think of some thing what do's that (made-up code)..

```
private object o;
private string myVersion; //...
if(o.HasChild("version"))
{
  myVersion = o.Child("version");
  o.DeleteChild("version");
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a type for the `o` instance?

Comment: There's no `HasChild` method on `object`, so your code won't even compile. What is the actual type of `o` ?

Comment: What's a "child"? do you wamt a dictionary/map?

Comment: How about using a `dictionnary<string,string>`?

Comment: @FelipeOriani
I have a type, when the child "version" is removed.
 I dont'n know the content of "version", so I cant create a type for it.

Comment: I add some more content at the initial question to explain better.

Comment: The "incomming object" is not an object, it looks like a plain string.  Convert it to objects you can manipulate in code with a JSON parser,   Newtonsoft.Json is a popular choice.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309725/newtonsoft-ignore-attributes).

Comment: I expand MyType with [JsonIgnore] public string version as @HansPassant recomented. Bevor and after I parse the object to string and the diff is my version.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `system.object`, I would try using a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

I'm not sure if you need to declare your parameter as `dynamic` or if `JObject` will work correctly.

Here is an article that describes it. (It is likely out-dated, but somewhere to start.)

[Using JSON.NET for dynamic JSON parsing](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing)